# Can I run Docker on GCP?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bamboo

The scenario is that I'm trying to get a Bamboo installation up on google cloud.

I had it set up on Linux, but NuGet is busted and refuses to authenticate with the server even though the same auth works on windows. I have a ticket open with them.

In the meanwhile, I decided to try setting it up on Windows since I know NuGet will work properly there, and it turns out it does. So I'm halfway through setting up a test build and it's now time to build a docker image. In order to do so, I need to install docker, right? So I do, but it won't start because Moby won't start. I'm assuming it's because you can't nest VMs. So now I'm stuck.

Somehow, AppVeyor has docker running in their images, but I don't know what their underlying infrastructure is.

So does anyone know if I can get docker running enough to build container images on Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [documentation guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/#docker_on_windows) which walks you through the steps to setup Docker on a Windows Server 2016 and later versions which include container support:

Install Docker:

1. Connect to the Windows Instance.
2. Open a PowerShell terminal as an administrator.
3. Install Docker from the Microsoft repositories:

   PS C:> Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force

   PS C:> Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
4. Run the following commands to work around known issues with Windows containers on Compute Engine:

Disable Receive Segment Coalescing:

```
PS C:> netsh netkvm setparam 0 *RscIPv4 0
```

Enable IPv6:

PS C:> reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters `
/v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0 /f

Restart the instance:

5. PS C:> Restart-Computer -Force

Follow the additional steps as described in the provided [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/#docker_on_windows) above.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try

Comment: do you happen to know if this is running the daemon in windows mode or linux? It runs in the background so there's no UI to switch. I need it in linux and I'm not sure how to check. It was my impression that the linux container was only available in 1709 which isn't really an option for us at the moment.

Comment: It is my understanding that it is a Windows Server Core [1] [2]. 
You may be able to achieve your goal with a mixed cluster [3]. 
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core
[2]: https://stefanscherer.github.io/docker-on-windows-server-1709/
[3]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWkqWJVeZow

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/)

Kubernetes Engine  is a managed, production-ready environment for deploying containerized applications. It brings our latest innovations in developer productivity, resource efficiency, automated operations, and open source flexibility to accelerate your time to market.

Kubernetes Engine supports the common Docker container format. (So you can run docker on Kubernetes Engine )